# Using Task to run continuous Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I want run a thread continuously. This thread would poll and check for card status. Here is a sample implementation:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var _cancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
           new Task(() => chkRequestTask(_cancelationTokenSource), _cancelationTokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Start();

           while (true)
           {
           }

        }

static bool chkRequestTask(CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource)
    {
        bool noRequest = false;

        while (!_cancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var RequestTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => noRequest = chkRequestTask(_cancellationTokenSource), _cancellationTokenSource.Token);

            if (noRequest)
            {
                _cancellationTokenSource.Token.WaitHandle.WaitOne(15000);
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for 15Seconds");

            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Checking the card");
            }



        }

        return noRequest;

    }
```

What I want to achieve here is `chkRequestTask` should be run on a separate thread. This would continously poll the status of the card. For this sample I'm simply doing : `Console.WriteLine("Checking the card");`.

Once it checks the status of the card it should sleep for 15secs for this sample only (in general it should check every 50ms, but for testing purposes I have kept 15secs).

But in the above sample it's not sleeping it's simply giving me `Checking the card` continuously. It's not sleeping at all for 15secs. What is wrong with this code ?

Comment: Not good: `while (true) {}`  This will suck up all the clock cycles of a CPU.

Comment: What you're trying to do with that status after polling? you want to poll till it returns true?

Comment: @SteveWellens. Just doing test here. It's a sample code. will remove that from production code. My main concern is get the 'chkRequestTask' running in a loop in a separate thread, as shown in my sample code above

Comment: What is the `card` and how does it behave?  Could you use a timer instead?  You may need to lock `card` as well `lock(card){ some code}`.

Comment: @FelixCastor: It's a DataAcquisition card from Adlink PCI-7250, I have a separate code for that, but I will plug that in when I get the above code working

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: While it's true, it should be doing 'Checking the card' and then wait for 15 secs'.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `chkRequestTask` recursively using `Task.Factory.StartNew` which you don't need at all.

It's not clear why you need to poll the status, better idea is to check any event or callback or `WaitHandle` provided by the card API you're talking about. That should keep you away from the pain.

If at all you believe polling is the only option you've left with, you can do it as follows.

```
static async Task ChkRequestTask(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (true)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        Console.WriteLine("Checking the card");
        bool status = PollTheCardForStatus();
        if(!status)
            break;

        await Task.Delay(15 * 1000, token);//Adjust the delay as you wish
    }
}
```

Else where in code, if possible await the call, If not then attach a continuation or use blocking `task.Wait`.

```
await ChkRequestTask(token);
```

This method doesn't need to return bool as you're returning from the method only when it is false, it is safe to assume the status is `false` when the `Task` returned from `ChkRequestTask` completes, which means poll returned false or the `CancellationToken` is cancelled, in which case you'll get `TaskCanceledException`

Comment: Thanks Sriram, I've just left the work. Will test this and come back to you. Regarding one of your concerns for the event callback or WaitHandle from the card, this was a first priority for me. But this particular card I have doesn't really have this facility. I have reconfirmed this with the support guys before.

Comment: Tested your logic, it seems to be working on the same thread. I want this to be running on a different thread.

Comment: @user726720 It's not a big deal. Just use `Task.Run` Example: `bool status = await Task.Run(()=>PollTheCardForStatus());`

Comment: or simply just call `Task.Run(()=> ChkRequestTask(token));` that should run the method in threadpool thread

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done this. It seems to be working properly. As it's a background thread it would exit when the application exits. Could someone advise If this is the right way to do it.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_dev = DASK.Register_Card(DASK.PCI_7250, 0);
        if (m_dev < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Register_Card error!");

        }

        FunctionToCall();

   }

private void FunctionToCall()
     {


        short ret;
        uint int_value;
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    ret = DASK.DI_ReadPort((ushort)m_dev, 0, out int_value);
                    if (ret < 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("D2K_DI_ReadPort error!");
                        return;
                    }
                    if (int_value > 0)
                   {
                       textBox2.Invoke(new UpdateText(DisplayText), Convert.ToInt32(int_value));

                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            });
        thread.Start();
        thread.IsBackground = true;
    }

    private void DisplayText(int i)
    {

        textBox2.Text = i.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Sriram, will test that and get back to, A bit busy here